# Blank screen show for 3 second before splash fragment while i Using Navigation component?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I have an Activity to navigate the splash fragment in default but before showing splash fragment show a blank screen for three seconds and then show the splash fragment. While I used the Navigation Component for fragment navigation. Please correct me if anyone knows.

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
NavController navController;
navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        }
        navController.navigate(R.id.splashFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by adding this line to the activity theme.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```